# How to disable W3 Total Cache “Performance” menu under multisite?

Tags: multisite, plugin-w3-total-cache

I came across the following article [W3 Total Cache - How to disable “Performance” menu under multisite?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44698/w3-total-cache-how-to-disable-performance-menu-under-multisite)

However on testing it with the latest version of WordPress 3.7 and W3 Total Cache v0.9.3 it seems to no longer work.

How can I update the code from the link above so it works

I also have the following code which works it removes the “Performance” from the admin top bar

```
//Remove Performance
function ds_w3tc_remove_adminbar() {
   global $wp_admin_bar;
     if ( ! is_super_admin() ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('w3tc');
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu','ds_w3tc_remove_adminbar',999);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to remove it with the menu slug `'w3tc_dashboard'` instead of `'w3tc_general'`:

i.e. use

```
remove_menu_page( 'w3tc_dashboard' );
```

instead of

```
remove_menu_page( 'w3tc_general' );
```

in the linked code example.